# Off-line installation of IRkernel for Jupyter/IPython notebook

Tags: r, ipython, offline-mode, jupyter

I am working on an off-line Ubuntu server and I would like to write an IPython notebook with only R code. I understand that for this to work I need to install the IRkernel. This shouldn't be a problem if the server was on-line, but unfortunately this is not the case. Any suggestions how to install the IRkernel off-line are greatly appreciated.

Oliver

(I have installed Anaconda3-2.2.0-x86-64 and R 3.0.2 on the Ubuntu server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Cube](https://launchpad.net/cube-server) to download the required Ubuntu packages (I think just `zmq3`) on an online computer and then install it on your offline server.

You would then need to download the needed R packages (`rzmq`,`repr`,`IRkernel`,`IRdisplay` - in `tar.gz` form)

To load those into your server you can use the following commands to install the R packages from source.

```
R CMD INSTALL package_ x.y.z.tar.gz
```

If you don't have permission to write to the standard library directory and can't use `sudo` to override, you can install it somewhere else via

```
R CMD INSTALL -l <user_lib> package_x.y.z.tar.gz
```

where `<user_lib>` is a directory you can write to. You may need to specify `lib.loc` when subsequently loading the package, if `<user_lib>` is not in `.libPaths`)

See [this manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html) for more information; `R CMD INSTALL --help` may also be useful

It's a less than ideal solution but it should work assuming there aren't any dependancies I've missed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the instructions. Unfortunately I could not find the R packages `repr`, `IRkernel` and `IRdisplay` in any other place than the Github repository (https://github.com/IRkernel) and there I can download them only as zip files.

Comment: @OliverTomic - Sorry. The `.zip` works fine too. You can install packages using `devtools` by unzipping a local zip file downloaded from github, and then running the install function  `install("path/to/unzipped_pkg_zip_file")`.

Comment: Thank very much for your for further instructions. I started with trying to install the Ubuntu package `zmq3`. What I found was `libzmq3`. I tried to install it but I didn't succeed since it depends on a number of other Ubuntu packages, amongst other a newer version of `libc6` (>= 2.17). The version of `libc6` already installed is (2.15).  When attempting to install `libc6` (2.19) I get the following error message: `lib6 breakes locales (<<2.19). locales (version 2.13) is present and installed. Installing lib6 would break locals, and deconfiguration is not permitted`